Why is the ServiceHost throwing an exception when I add a UdpAnnouncementEndpoint to ServiceDiscoveryBehavior?
The ServiceHost is throwing a NullReferenceException when I try to facilitate the service announcement. I do it exactly as described here

Below is a complete running code illustrating the problem.
I ran this as .netFramework 4.8 console application with references added to System.ServiceModel and System.ServiceModel.Discovery.
Since someone will probably ask, using UdpDiscovery does work correctly.
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Discovery;

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IServerCallback))]
public interface IServer
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Connect();
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IServerCallback
{
    [OperationContract]
    void KeepAlive();
}

public class MyServiceHost<TContract, TServer> where TServer : TContract where TContract : IServer
{
    private readonly ServiceHost _serviceHost;
    private const string MyIp = "10.82.83.84";

    public MyServiceHost(TServer server)
    {
        var uri = new Uri($"net.tcp://{MyIp}:8586");
        _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(server, uri);
        StartServer();
    }

    private void StartServer()
    {
        //Endpoint.
        var contract = typeof(TContract);
        _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(contract, new NetTcpBinding(), contract.Name);

        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/discovery-announcements-and-announcement-client#announcements-on-the-service

        ServiceDiscoveryBehavior serviceDiscoveryBehavior = new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior();
        serviceDiscoveryBehavior.AnnouncementEndpoints.Add(new UdpAnnouncementEndpoint());
        _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceDiscoveryBehavior);

        _serviceHost.Open();
    }
}
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class Server : IServer
{
    public void Connect()
    { }
}
public static class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myServiceHost = new MyServiceHost<IServer, Server>(new Server());
        while (Console.ReadLine() != "q"){}
    }
}



In the question you describe the WCF service implemented using the console, but is your configuration set up in the form of a web.config file or code? I recommend that you check to see if your configuration is initialized, and that you configure a log file to see how it works.

Thanks for helping out! Please note that I have provided a complete running code that reproduces the problem. You only need to create a console application and replace everything in the default Program.cs with my provided code.  Before running add the above mentioned ServiceModel references and change the const called MyIp to your Ip address or localhost. There is no more to it. No external config file.
